# Determine the polynomial $P_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^n n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n$ by using the binomial theorem.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Determine the polynomial $$P_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^n n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n$$ by using the binomial theorem.

My issue with this question is taking the $n$th derivative after using the binomial theorem.  I understand what will happen but I don't know how to set it out properly with the sigma so that is it clear to the reader. Can anyone provide a model answer?

Comment: Why don't you add what you've tried and where you're stuck so it's more clear.

Comment: You might like to take a look at this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendrePolynomial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the binomial theorem and the linearity of the differential operator, we have that
$$P_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^n n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}x^{2k}\right)=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{n!}\frac{d^n\left(x^{2k}\right)}{dx^n}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Is the derivative part $\frac{d^n\left(x^{2k}\right)}{dx^n}=\frac{2k!}{(2k-n)!}x^{2k-n}$?

Comment: Yes. it is $\frac{(2k)!}{(2k-n)!}x^{2k-n}$ (it  is zero for $2k<n$).

Comment: The issue is that $k<n/2$ gives negative exponent, so what do we do about that?

Comment: Sorry, take $\sum_{k=\lceil n/2\rceil}^n$